# Set projection mode in OpenGL 3?

Tags: opengl, spatial, projection, opengl-3

In old OpenGL versions spatial projection (where objects become smaller with growing distance) could be enabled via a call to

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
```

(at least as far as I remember this was the call to enable this mode).

In OpenGL 3 - when this slow stack-mode is no longer used - this function does not work any more.

So how can I have the same spatial effect here? What is the intended way for this?

Comment: You have to multiply the vertices by an projection matrix in the vertex shader. I recommend to use the [GLM library](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) and e.g. [glm::perspective()](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00665.html#ga747c8cf99458663dd7ad1bb3a2f07787) to calculate the projection matrix (or `glm::ortho`, `glm::frustum`, ...)

Comment: Furthermore, `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)` does not enable perspective projection. It just tells OpenGL to apply all subsequent matrix manipulation calls to the projection matrix. Whether or not that contains a perspective projection is an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

You've completely misunderstood what `glMatrixMode` actually did. The old, legacy OpenGL fixed function pipeline kept a set of matrices around, which were all used indiscriminately when drawing stuff. The two most important matrices were:

- the *modelview* matrix, which is used to describe the transformation from model local space into view space. View space is still kind of abstract, but it can be understood as the world transformed into the coordinate space of the "camera". Illumination calculations happened in that space.
- the *projection* matrix, which is used to describe the transformation from view space into clip space. Clip space is an intermediary stage right before reaching device coordinates (there are few important details involved in this, but those are not important right now), which mostly involves applying the *homogenous divide* i.e. scaling the clip coordinate vector by the reciprocal of its w-component.

The fixed transformation pipeline *always* was

```
position_view := Modelview · position
do illumination calculations with position_view
position_clip := Projection · position_view
position_pre_ndc := position_clip · 1/position_clip.w
```

In legacy OpenGL the modelview and projection matrix are always there. `glMatrixMode` is a selector, which of the existing matrices are subject to the operations done by the matrix manipulation functions. One of these functions is `glFrustum` which generates and multiplies a perspective matrix, i.e. a matrix which will create a perspective effect through the homogenous divide.

> So how can I have the same spatial effect here? What is the intended way for this?

You generate a perspective matrix of the desired properties, and use it to transform the vertex attribute you designate as model local position into clip space and submit that into the `gl_Position` output of the vertex shader. The usual way to do this is by passing in a modelview and a projection matrix as uniforms.

The most bare bones GLSL vertex shader doing that would be

```
#version 330
uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat4 projection;
in vec4 pos;
void main(){
    gl_Position = projection * modelview * pos;
}
```

As for generating the projection matrix: All the popular computer graphics math libraries got you covered and have functions for that.